# Can I not use a list in my code and still get the same result?

Tags: python, list

I was just wondering if I am able to not use the list in the code below and still get the same results:

```
colors = random.choice(['blue' , 'red' , 'green'])

print(colors)
```

Comment: Give it a try and see the result!

Comment: what do you mean exactly ? You have to specify somewhere the information concerning the available colors ("blue", "red" and "green"). Are you asking if you can use another type of variable to store these colors ?

Comment: What I am asking is can I make the code more complex by not using a list and without changing the results

Comment: You could always look at the documentation for `random.choice`.

Comment: Why would you want to make your code complex? Simplicity is key!

Comment: "can I make the code more complex" You can make any code *arbitrarily* more complex by adding useless abstractions. That is an open-ended goal, which makes it not suitable for [so]. Do you have a *concrete* goal in mind?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call the function without the list.

If you look at the docs... https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

...it states the choice function accept a single argument `seq`.

This suggests that argument needs to be a sequence.

We can dig into this a little further by looking at the typeshed interface file - https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/dd73f117f04306b0ccf840aa497fc89a0d49c083/stdlib/random.pyi#L18

These describe the type of data the function accepts and returns.

This explains that the function requires a `Sequence`. A sequence describes a collection of indexed objects (basically a list).

If the signature for `random.choice` looked like this (note the `*` before `args`)...

```
def choice(*args):
    ...
```

... then you wouldn't supply the argument as a list.

See this article... https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#using-the-python-args-variable-in-function-definitions